# Append & populate first name, last name columns using full name column in same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server and I have a column called "Full Name" that I pulled from a separate table. I have a column for First Name & Last name (among many other columns).

Here is the code that I found and used and it worked:

```
SELECT Full_Name,
       LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1)  AS First_Name,
       RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name)) AS Last_Name
FROM   table_name
```

That extracted the name, but upon viewing the entire table using this command:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

I don't see it? Is there a method that I can use to insert the data into the First_name and Last_name columns **without adding any additional Rows**

Thank you !

Comment: You need to add the columns to the table, then use an UPDATE statement (not a SELECT statement) to place the data into those columns. But how will you maintain this data?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps creating a view wil be sufficient:

```
CREATE VIEW table_name_v
SELECT Full_Name,
       LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1)  AS First_Name,
       RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name)) AS Last_Name
FROM   table_name
```

Then instead of using the table name in subsequent queries you use the view instead

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_v
```

The problem you face otherwise is that if you add first and last name columns to this table that you now end-up with 3 columns to maintain, or that you may need to replace the data entry screen(s) that use full_name to start using first and last name columns instead.

If you really do want to proceed by adding the columns, you could try using "computed columns" which would avoid the necessity to change data entry screens etc.

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable(
    full_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL 
 );
 INSERT INTO mytable(full_name) VALUES ('fred flintstone');
 select * from mytable
```

> | full_name |
> | --- |
> | fred flintstone |

```
alter table mytable
add 
    first_name as LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1)
  , Last_Name as RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name))

select * from mytable
```

> | full_name | first_name | Last_Name |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | fred flintstone | fred | flintstone |

*db<>fiddle for computed columns [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=da7ed2183128207fb08bb53c866ac627)*

If you realy do want to store these 2 separate columns (rather than computing them) then you need to add the columns to your table and run an update statement to populate them as follows:

```
alter table mytable
add 
  first_name varchar(100)
, last_name varchar(100)

update mytable
set 
  first_name = LEFT(Full_Name,CHARINDEX(' ',Full_Name )-1)
, Last_Name = RIGHT(Full_Name, LEN(Full_Name)- CHARINDEX(' ', Full_Name))
```

*db<>fiddle for adding columns and updating [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b20c876aaeeeb3785573a29e01f32be7)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that solved it! I think youre rightthat  I'll just have the columns created already and that way when new data is added/taken away Id just have to run the update function to grab the new info.